# Meteor async call to Instagram API not returning on client side. Returns on server side

Tags: meteor

Server side:

```
Meteor.methods({

    getFromInstagram: function(){

        console.log("called!");

        Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
        var myFuture = new Future();

        var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?access_token=[ACCESSTOKEN]";

        Meteor.http.get(url, function(error, results){
            if(error){
                myFuture.throw(error);
            } else {
                myFuture.return(results);
            }
        });

        console.log( myFuture.wait() );
        return myFuture.wait();

    }

});
```

Client side:

```
instagramContent = Meteor.call("getFromInstagram");
console.log(instagramContent);
```

The server side console log works and returns an object.

The client side console log in Chrome console returns undefined. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side will always be async.

Try something like:

```
instagramContent = Meteor.call("getFromInstagram", function (error, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

From the documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call):

> On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That worked. BTW, is my server code for my `Meteor.methods` correct? Do I still need to specify the use of `futures / fibers`?

Comment: Doh: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call  `On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method.`

Comment: I don't know other ways to do it, besides futures. I've seen other implementations, but wasn't able to find examples just now, sorry.